# Strange caching issue

Tags: php, html, google-chrome

If you view the content of the following file:

http://swiftdigital.ltd.uk/wp-content/themes/bigbangwp_child/style.css?ver=4.4

The content is different to if you view the same file but with 4.5 on the end:

http://swiftdigital.ltd.uk/wp-content/themes/bigbangwp_child/style.css?ver=4.5

The contents of the file on the server are:

```
/*
Theme Name:     BigBangWP Child Theme
Description:    Edit style.css, function.php or copy theme original files and customize it on your own
Author:         Brankic1979
Template:       bigbangwp
*/
@import "css/colors/color-blue.css";
```

There is no caching on the server so why does version 4.4 return the old contents of the file?

Comment: Could your browser be caching it? For what's worth, if I `curl` both URLs, I get the exact same contents back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your website (www.swiftdigital.ltd.uk) uses Cloudflare. By default Cloudflare will cache JS files and that appears to be what's happening here.

Purging your cache on Cloudflare will fix this.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169246-How-do-I-purge-my-cache-

Comment: Of course it does I always forget about that! Thanks!